# Why Ubuntu One pretends to sychronize files, but it doesn't?

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, sync

I have my Ubuntu One account configured in both Ubuntu 11.10 and iOS (ipod-touch). The photos from the iOS were successfully uploaded, but in Ubuntu One, although it shows the "syncing" and "synchronized" marks over the icons, the files are not showing in the website (one.ubuntu.com).

In short: My files are not showing in the Ubuntu One website, although the icons have the "uploaded" mark.

Any idea what can be wrong here?

**obs1**: Also, not sure if it's related, the icon-marks will show only when I open the Ubuntu One Control Panel. It shows the message "file was uploaded", but there's nothing online.

**obs2**: The folder I'm trying to synchronize is 30mb size. And my connection is 8mbps.

Comment: Do they actually upload sooner or later? It happens to me too: I think I've already waited up to 10 minutes to upload a 50 Kb archive... But I've never had a situation where the files were not uploaded at all.

Comment: @Mr.Pixel It never uploads. I have configured it a month ago, and I gone to check it now, there's no file uploaded. In nautilus, it shows the icon-marks for "synching" and "uploaded", but there's no file online.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, it sounds like a bug, but then again, 30MB can be relatively heavy if you have a standard 8Mbits connexion (that is 8Mbits down, but something like 256kbits up). If that's the case, 256kbits would result in a 32 kB/s upload speed (8 bits = 1 byte), and still, that would be the theoretical upper limit. You would more likely be around 20-25 kB/s. In the best case, your upload would easily take 20min, but maybe there is a hidden timeout somewhere? Or your connexion is simply too unstable? I would also not be surprised to see that UOne does not support resuming uploads...

Comment: Also, http://askubuntu.com/questions/56020/is-ubuntu-one-robust-enough-for-serious-use seems to have some related information, like, does the log show anything interesting? cat ~/.cache/ubuntuone/log/syncdaemon.log | tail

Comment: @TomBrito - to be honest - I think this is a duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16592/how-can-i-tell-whether-ubuntu-one-file-sync-is-working-and-what-progress-it-is

Comment: I had a similar problem with my Android tablet: files changed on the tablet were not uploaded. The answer I got from U1 support: "Currently the Ubuntu One Files app on android only uploads.files (auto-uploads
photos). You will need to upload the file again to make the new version available.
We hope to add a form of syncing in a future release." Perhaps this is the case for the iOS version too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the +50 bounty would be nice, askUbuntu is probably the wrong place for this. You should instead open a support request on https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ or a bug report on Launchpad by running `ubuntu-bug ubuntuone-client`, so that the issue can be more appropriately looked at.

Comment: Maybe, but, before, I have to be sure that it's a bug. Sometimes it's just something I don't know how to use.

Comment: @TomBrito If your question starts with something other than "How do I…" then it's probably a bug or misfeature you're dealing with. Also, the official support channels for U1 are to use the contact link I mentioned above, or file a bug report. You will get a much faster, and more accurate response. You can also join #ubuntuone IRC channel on Freenode, but it is best to ask questions there during weekday hours in Europe/US East time zones.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens that if you had the same folder create before it wouldn't sync it. Also, if you have a folder full of files and try to sync the parent folder, it will only synchronize the parent folder and leave the rest of the files unsynced. You should try to sync a new empty folder and then add the rest of the files.

I totally agree with dobey. The +50 bounty would be very nice but this must be certainly a bug to report.

Comment: None of these work for me. It's not an folder created before, it's my Documents folder, and it's not even creating this folder online (although it shows as synchronized in Nautilus). Also, I tried the new empty folder, and the behavior is the same. Anyway, thanks for answering!